# Update / Add Navigation Properties with Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Repository and Unit Of Work Pattern with Entity Framework 6.

My Entities (Model Classes) have the following relationship:

```
                            Article 
     ______________ __________|__________ _______________
    |              |                     |               |
   Tags         Images     References   Authors        Reviewers
```

Whenever an `Article` is created, data will be inserted into all tables (i.e. `Article`, `Tags`, `Images`, `References`, `Authors` and `Reviewers`. There is a one-to-many relationship between `Article` and the other child tables. The `Add` method will be passed an `Article` object which will look like following:

```
public class Article 
{
   public int articleId {get;set;}
   ICollection Tags {get;set;}
   Icollection Images {get;set;}
   ICollection Authors {get;set;}
   ICollection Reviewers {get;set;}
}
```

Adding this to the database is simple and I am doing it as following:

```
public void Add (Article arc)
{
  this.context.Article.Add(arc); 
}
```

For update, I am not getting what would be the best way of doing this. User can pass on object of Article with amended Navigation properties and/Or added more. 
e.g. Existing Reviewer can be amended as well as added more.

I have composite key in each of the navigation properties (e.g. for `Tags` its `TagId` and `ArticleId`).

Please suggest some approach

Comment: Here is the article explaining Unit of Work with Repository pattern. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Essential reading:  Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Making Do with Absent Foreign Keys http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708747.aspx